# Recommended way to redefine Bootstrap features in Wordpress plugin

Tags: css, wordpress, plugins, twitter-bootstrap

I have to develop a plugin for Wordpress. Most of the styles are based on the Bootstrap CSS library. However, for some design decisions I have to redefine the default behaviour of bootstrap. What is the recommended way how Bootstrap features are to be redefined?
One example: I need a zebra striped table. The bootstrap class table-striped has already much of the features I need. However the stripes should be green not gray and the contrast should be a bit stronger. In addition some of the features of the Bootstrap class table must  e changed – for example padding and font-size.
The clients who are installing my plugin may or may not update to new versions of Wordpress and Bootstrap. Some of the might be unable to change the Wordpress or Bootstrap installation which exists already on their web host. For this reason it is probably not a solution to modify Wordpress files or the Bootstrap original CSS. In addition: The solution must work with various browsers – not just browsers of the last generation.
I have looked in various forums and found a number of suggestions – including .less and recompiling a modified version of Bootstrap. However, many of these solutions look more like hacks or “work-arounds” rather than a “recommended software architecture” - a kind industrial standard. Other solutions work only with very new browsers.

To summarize my question: How should we integrate modifications like these outlined above into a Wordpress / Bootstrap environment?

Comment: Are you rolling your own theme or using something like [WP-Bootstrap](http://320press.com/wpbs/)?

Comment: I am using Bootstrap. And from this fact comes the problem of my question. If I used my own theme I could control all features, of course.

Answer (score 0):

If you're worried about Bootstrap updates you could always do some kind of "child theme" type of treatment: You can be using your main style.css to overwrite the bootstrap styles. Then your WordPress theme and Bootstrap styles can be independent.

Comment: I can define new classes in my style.css. For example:
.zebra-striped {
  margin:0; padding:0;
}

My HTML will look like this:
<table class="table table-condensed table-striped zebra-striped" id="table_id">

Is this the solution you recommended?
Can I control in this way colour and contrast of the zebra striping? If yes: what properties do I have to redefine?

Comment: Bootstrap already has .table-striped for striped tables. It seems to me you'd reset the colours on this. I guess if your issue is making this client friendly your goal should be about smart defaults, correct?